# Uncaught Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

My code is syntactically correct but then also I am facing the error when I console log.

My PHP ,HTML , javascript code goes like this :

```
<html>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="Fees">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
      <option value="500">Above $500</option>
  <option value="9000">Above $9000</option>
  <option value="1500">Below $1500</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" values="Choose options">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['Fees'])) {
        $selected = $_POST['Fees'];

    } else {
        echo 'Please select the value.';
    }
    }
?>
<script>
spge = '<?php echo $selected ;?>';
fee_selected=parseInt(spge);
console.log("Fees Selected : "+fee_selected);
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token in PHP

Comment: I assume that is all in one file?

Comment: Yes , in one file .

Comment: Then show it as it appears in one file without any lines of text in the missdle

Comment: @RiggsFolly  : Uncaught Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token in PHP

Comment: Errors: ALWAYS show us **all** the error message, errors like that come with line number and file name where the error is caused

Comment: And again, please post the code EXACTLY as it appears in your real code file, without any additions or ommissons

Comment: Give the code in your question, the error cannot be explained.

Comment: You are echoing your POST data *as is*. This error highly depend on the data you send. You basically inject raw PHP via POST data, which is a *massive* security risk. And also probably the cause of your error. This code is very bad design and your not be used in production

Comment: What should be done @SkaveRat

Comment: Add `$selected = 0;` before `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: Did the answer work for you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, **$selected** is not always defined. And you have two if statements indented but only one echo of "**Please select the value**".  One way to fix it is

```php
<html>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="Fees">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
      <option value="500">Above $500</option>
  <option value="9000">Above $9000</option>
  <option value="1500">Below $1500</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" values="Choose options">
</form>
<?php
    $selected = 0;  //<----------------
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if(!empty($_POST['Fees'])) {
        $selected = $_POST['Fees'];
      } 
      else {
        echo 'Please select the value.';
      }
    } 
    else {
       echo 'Please select the value.'; //<--------------
    }
?>
<script>
spge = '<?php echo $selected ;?>';
fee_selected=parseInt(spge);
console.log("Fees Selected : "+fee_selected);
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```